# Understanding strcpy with array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, strcpy

I have a little code that merge `strcpy` array and pointer. I don't understand why the code displays `"Good exam"`. I see that after the call to `strcpy`, `ptr` contains `"lexam"`. So, can you explain when the value of `a[]` changes?

```
char a[50] = "Good luck!";
char b[50] = { 'i','n',' ', 't','h','e',' ','e','x','a','m','\0' };
char* ptr = a + 5; cout << *ptr;
strcpy(ptr, &b[7]); 
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++)
    cout << ptr[i];
cout << a;
```

Comment: It is changed by `strcpy`, as expected? What does "why the code display what it display "Good exam"" mean?

Comment: *after the line of strcpy ptr contain "lexam"* - `ptr` is a pointer, it contains an address; that's all, Specifically it contains the address of the fifth char from base of array `a`,  All `strcpy` did was modify the memory referred to by that address, and in so doing, the content of the array `a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    [0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10] [11]
a = [G][o][o][d][ ][l][u][c][k][!][\0]
b = [i][n][ ][t][h][e][ ][e][x][a][m]  [\0]

char* ptr = a + 5;

      [0][1][2][3][4][5]
ptr = [l][u][c][k][!][\0]

        [0][1][2][3][4] 
&b[7] = [e][x][a][m][\0]
```

What you are doing is replacing the content that starts in `b[7]`and overwriting whatever starts in `ptr` (that is equivalent to `a + 5` or `&a[5]`).

Hence after strcpy you have:

```
      [0][1][2][3][4][5]
ptr = [e][x][a][m][\0][\0]
```

Note that the place where the symbol `!` was present is now a `\0` because `&b[7]` had length 4 while `ptr` had length 5.